# Группировка с агрегацией в строку

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица (group_id int, text varchar(max), sum decimal(19,2))

данные

```
1 | qwe | 3.00

1 | asd | 5.00

2 | zxc | 10.00

2 | 123 | 15.00
```

Нужно индексированное представление, которое вернет

```
1 | qwe,asd | 8.00

2 | zxc,123 | 25.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае обычное представление можно создать, *индексированное* - нет.

Любой способ, которым можно выполнить конкатенацию в SqlServer попадёт под ограничения ([ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms191432.aspx), см. раздел *Дополнительные требования*).

Дело в том, что если в индексированном представлении используется агрегация, то оно не только должно "уметь" агрегировать данные, при добавлении или изменении строк в таблицах, на которых оно основано, но также и деагрегировать их, при удалении строк. И с целью улучшения производительности это делается инкрементально, а не полным перестроением индекса.

С функциями наподобие `sum()` и `count()` это можно сделать легко и однозначно. Если добавили строк в таблицу, то значения их `[sum]` добавятся к соответствующим строкам индексированного представления. Если удалили строки, то их `[sum]` вычтутся.

С конкатенацией нельзя такого сделать. Допустим у нас есть строки `asd`, `qwe` и `d,q` в одной группе. Конкатенируя их через запятую мы получим в индексированном представлении строку `asd,qwe,d,q`.

Теперь, допустим, удаляется строка с `d,q`. Как определить в каком месте в `asd,qwe,d,q` нужно убрать `d,q`? Однозначно - никак. Поэтому такие вещи и запрещены.

Альтернатива - дополнительная постоянная таблица, которая будет обновляться (например, триггером) при изменении данных в основной таблице.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT group_id, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ','), sum(``sum``) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY group_id;
```

Comment: какой аналог для T-sql функции Group_Concat() ?

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, в sql-server такой функции нет, но аналогичного поведения можно добиться с помощью функции stuff
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53/tsql-equivalent-for-groupconcat-function?forum=transactsql

Comment: нашел если кому интересно [GROUP_CONCAT for SQL Server](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @VladimirPavluk, это не то что мне нужно. Для каждого отдельного столбца придется запрашивать одни и те же данные. Я до пенсии буду ждать выполнения этого запроса... к тому же тут еще говорят что индексированное представление мне не создать

Comment: iRumba мне не понятно почему это не то что вам нужно. Почему Для каждого отдельного столбца придется запрашивать одни и те же данные - поясните что вы здесь имеете ввиду, я просто не понимаю скрытой за этими словами информации. Неужели SELECT group_id, sum(``sum``) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY group_id; это обращение занимает значительное время обработки? поясните свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

```
select group_id
,left(
    (
        select [text] + ','
        from table t2
        where t2.group_id = t1.group_id
        for xml path('')
    )
    ,len (
        (
            select [text] + ','
            from table t2
            where t2.group_id = t1.group_id
            for xml path('')
        )
    ) - 1
) as s123
, sum([sum]) as [sum]
from table t1
group by group_id
```